# How to instantiate object on correct position?

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, spawn

I have one really big issue with my game . When i try press play when he spawn first prefab everything is correct X position is -0.604f , z is -1.49f..But when i spawn second object the second and the third object get spawned on wrong position of x and z.

On the second object X position is not good ( in this case second Z position of object is -1.208 and i need here same value as before -0.604) I really don't know why this happens and I don't know how i can change Z position when i spawn third object in other side so if first two objects are on right and left and when i spawn third object he get Z position of -4.968 which is not correct because I need on third position on Z = -1.655984 and i am getting on third object z position of ~-5f.

Here is my code to spawn objects..

```
public class StackPiecesSpawner : Singleton<StackPiecesSpawner> {

    public GameObject stackPrefab;
    [SerializeField] public Transform StackPieceSpawnPoint;

    [SerializeField] public float PieceSpawnSize = 0.1f;

    [SerializeField] public float PieceSpawnWidth = 1.0f;

    [SerializeField] private float speed = 1f;

    public Vector3 OriginalSpawnPointPosition;

    protected override void Awake()
    {
        base.Awake();
        OriginalSpawnPointPosition = StackPieceSpawnPoint.position;
    }

    public void SpawnNextStackPiece()
    {
        //StackPieceSpawnPoint.position += new Vector3(0f,PieceSpawnSize,0f);
        StackPieceSpawnPoint.position += new Vector3(0.604f, 0.1f, -1.656f);

        //GameObject go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        GameObject go = GameObject.Instantiate(stackPrefab);
        //go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(PieceSpawnWidth,PieceSpawnSize,PieceSpawnWidth);
        go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.4f, 0.4f,0.05f);

        go.transform.position = nextSpawnPosition();

        go.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        go.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;

        go.AddComponent<StackPiece>();

        go.transform.parent = transform;
        go.transform.name = "StackPiece_" + (StackPiecesManager.StackPieces.Count + 1);

        StackPiece piece = go.GetComponent<StackPiece>();
        piece.TargetTransform = StackPieceSpawnPoint;

        piece.Speed = speed;
        StackPiecesManager.Instance.AddNewPiece(piece);
    }

    private Vector3 nextSpawnPosition()
    {
        System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
        int num = rnd.Next(0, 100);

        Vector3 modifier = new Vector3();


        modifier = num < 50 ? Vector3.back : Vector3.left;


        modifier *= StackPiecesManager.Instance.SpawnDistance;
        Vector3 returned = (StackPieceSpawnPoint.position - modifier) + Vector3.up * (StackPiecesManager.Instance.ExtraHeight);
        // returned = (StackPieceSpawnPoint.position) + Vector3.up * (StackPiecesManager.Instance.ExtraHeight);
        return returned;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        StackPieceSpawnPoint.position = OriginalSpawnPointPosition;
    }

}
```

Comment: StackPieceSpawnPoint.position += new Vector3(0.604f, 0.1f, -1.656f); -- Why do you need this line? That's why your gameobject is starting in different positions.

Comment: @Gray_Rhino , 
Because it spawns a object on correct position and after first object spawn others are not on correct positions..

Comment: Then just use "=" not "+=".

Comment: @Gray_Rhino, But that doesn't solve my problem of second object spawn..Thank you for point me to this issue ..

Comment: Vector3 returned = (StackPieceSpawnPoint.position - modifier) + Vector3.up * (StackPiecesManager.Instance.ExtraHeight); - for the second spawn position this line is causing the problem. For "modifer" use (x,y,z) instead of back, forward. That way you will have control over exact diraction.

Comment: Gray_Rhino, When I remove + from "+="  the game is not spawning on position where i need to spawn first object, can you send me email to cikatuna@gmail.com to take a look better at my code maybe we can figure out what is wrong here, of course if you have some time ...btw how i can use x,y,z in return statement, can you write me example on my code if you want :) .. p.s. thank you for your time

Comment: Use explicit position instantiation following [the doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) - the third one. Try assigning your instantiating position.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot completely answer this question as not all the code and context is available, however, I could maybe point you in the right direction.

**Parent-child relationship**
In the SpawnNextStackPiece you instantiate a prefab and have its current parent transform equal the current transform(of the object this script is attached to), check if the transform you're changing the parent to is shifting each time a prefab is instantiated. I tend to avoid changing parent transforms, I usually try to attach it to different parents and change the actual objects offset not the parents, it can be easier to manage. **I suspect `go.transform.parent = transform;` is causing a problem**.

**Diagnosing the problem through zeroing out values**
Try forcefully making the z-axis 0 so you can see how much it is getting offset by each time it spawns, that may make diagnosing the problem much easier. Do this with `StackPieceSpawnPoint.position = new Vector3(0.604f, 0.1f,0f);`

Comment: Aiden Faulconer, I really appreciate your reply but this is not solution for me , when i put 0 in the third parameter my obejcts are not on correct position.. Maybe the parent solution can help but i don't have idea how i can implement it into my code?

p.s. to be honest when i use primitive object cube everything works allright , when i use my prefab beside the unity primitive object cube nothing spawns correctly only first object is on good position others gets moved idk why..

Comment: No problem, try using a different approach altogether than messing with parent-child relationships and see how that works out for you. Maybe just don't do it at all, it would probably work if you manually set the position of the parent in the editor rather than through a script. Try that and tell me how you go!

Comment: Sorry but even if i make it a child of parent it doesn't works i don't know why my scripts add to next object double value on X position and why the hell third object get spawned on wrong z axis... Please find some soltuion for me guys :/